# React router V4 - Switch not rendering in production

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router

### Problem

When building my project for production with react, react-router V4 and webpack, the "Switch" is not rendering any matching routes. But it works in a development environment.

### What I've tried

I used the boilerplate here : https://github.com/KleoPetroff/react-webpack-boilerplate

My Router.js is simply :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../components/App';
import About from '../components/About';

const Root = () => {
return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
);
};

export default Root;
```

And the components App.js and About.js are simply :

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <h2 id="heading">
      Hello ReactJS
      <Link to="/about">here</Link>
    </h2>
  );
};

export default App;
```

About.js

```
import React from 'react';

const About = () => {
  return (
    <h2 id="heading">
      About ReactJS
    </h2>
  );
};

export default About;
```

### My Research

I went through plenty of stackoverflow's similar question (more related about react-router-redux apparently) but I got no working answers for the moment.

I tried to implement the app using different webpack configs like the one with react-create-app repo.

I'm not sure if it's related to the latest version of react-router or with my webpack config.

It sounds like a dumb and easy problem but I can't find answers anywhere in the web.

**So my question is, how do I make the switch component match the correct paths ?**

Comment: what do you mean by not rendering any matching routes? do you get completely white page, or your app is not rendering the route itself?

Comment: You might need to configure your webserver (check the asnwer below), or you can use "HashRouter" from react-router. it doesn't require any server configuration.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, actually I get a complete white page because no routes seems matched. If I remove path="/" and do a basic <Route component={App}></Route>, it actually renders the component. So I believe the default location for the router is wrong in production.

I also think it has something to do with webserver, I only tried it locally because I thought it would be handled by webpack by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue recently and resolved it by resolving all requests back to my index.html in my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually I have this in mind but I thought it would work locally (thanks to webpack ?) when launching index.html in my build folder. I need to setup an apache server to try if it's working using an .htaccess file.

Comment: I tried to setup .htaccess for my apache server and it seems to have corrected the problem for now. I'll mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Glad to hear it resolved your issue, let me know if you have any further issues with this.